# Android RecyclerView getChildAt() and getChildAdapterPosition()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I saw a sample code and couldn't understand the meaning of the following method:

```
public int getAdapterPositionForIndex(RecyclerView parent, int index) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(index);
        return parent.getChildAdapterPosition(child);
    }
```

My understanding is what's returned should always equal to index, but my debugger obviously doesn't say so. Since the docs are not explaining well the difference between getChildAt() and getChildAdapterPostion(), I hope I could get some expert insights here.

Comment: `getChildAt()` give an index and return the corresponding item from adapter, `getChildAdapterPostion` give an item and return it's index, i hope this help you ;-)

Comment: Hi, @Farrokh Yes, I understand getChildAt() is returning the view and getChildAdapterPosition() is returning an index. Let me rephrase my question: how come the return value of the `getAdapterPositionForIndex ` method does not always equal to index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as per my understanding `getChildAt()` is a method of `ViewGroup` . And it does Returns the view at the specified position in the group.

Since `RecyclerView` is an `AdapterView` i.e items get recycle when goes out of boundary it returns null for `#getChildAt()`.

**I am not sure whats the exact reason may be some should explain this**

On other hand `#getChildAdapterPosition()` Return the adapter position that the given child view added to.
Look at the code below :(Only adding the essential)

```
findViewById(R.id.b1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager= (LinearLayoutManager) rvNumber.getLayoutManager();
            final View child = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(30);
            if(child!=null) {
                int i = rvNumber.getChildAdapterPosition(child);
                Log.i("pos", i + "");
            }else{
                Log.i("pos",  "View is null");
            }
        }
    });
```

Nothing complex here! I laid down 60 items in `RecyclerView` just a `TextView`. In which 10 items are showing at a time in list . So the first time 10 views will be laid down (0-9).

When i call the above code on clicking on button it gives me a `null` view . Cause Views is not inflated yet for position 30. But after scrolling to position 30 it returns the view and hence its position by  `getChildAdapterPosition()` which will be 30 also .

I think you should make a sample and play around with it for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

FROM DOCS

[**`getChildAdapterPosition()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#getChildAdapterPosition(android.view.View))

- Return the adapter position that the given child view corresponds to.

[**`getChildAt()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#getChildAt(int))

- Returns the view at the specified position in the group.

> The Difference

It Means the `getChildAdapterPosition()` method return the the position of `View` inside `recyclerview` adapter

AND

the `getChildAt()` method returns the `View` from a `viewGroup` of specific position

In short 
The Both method are different `getChildAt()` is retuning `view` from a `viewGroup`  while the other `getChildAdapterPosition()` retuning the postion of a view in `recyclerview` adapter

Comment: @Downvoters pls. explain exactly what's wrong with this answer so that I can address?